# Select a random node on every reload

Tags: neoscms

I want to select a random node on every reload. My fusion file looks like this:

```
randomInt = ${Math.randomInt(0, q(node).children(Neos.Neos:Document).count()}
randomNode = ${q(node).children(Neos.Neos:Document).get(this.randomInt)}
```

Unfortunately the result is stored in the cache. That means that only after the cache get flushed a new node will be returned. How can I prevent this? I have already experimented with the cache rules a little bit, but I didn't come up with a solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element that I want to use is on every page. That's why something like the `unchached` mode would be a really bad idea.

In my situation the output is only a array of strings. So I did following in my Fusion.

1. Generate "almost" a Array in Fusion

   ```
   allMyStrings = Neos.Fusion:Loop {
       items = ${q(node).children(Neos.Neos:Document).get()}
       itemName = 'node'
       itemRenderer = ${"'" + q(node).property('testString') + "'"}
       @glue = ','
   }
   ```
2. Pick a random array in JS

   ```
   <p id='replaceMe'></p>
   <script>
     var quoteArray = [{allMyStrings -> f:format.raw()}]
     var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * quoteArray.length);
     var randomElement = quoteArray[randomIndex];
     document.getElementById('replaceMe').outerHTML= '<p>' + randomElement + '</p>';
   </script>
   ```

A bit hacky but it works and it don't harm the performance of the website